# How do I check if a value in Clojure hash-map exists and equals nil?

Tags: clojure

When programming in Clojure, I get the same fair answer for both questions:

```clj
(nil? (:potato {}))
=> true
(nil? (:potato {:potato nil}))
=> true
```

This sometimes leads to confusion. Is there a function that would help me discover the difference?

Something like:

```clj
(property-nil? {} :potato)
=> false
(property-nil? {:potato nil} :potato)
=> true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a default value with the map lookup, supplying any non-`nil` value as the default. In this example I am using the string "anything":

```clj
(nil? (:potato {:potato nil} "anything"))
; => true

(nil? (:potato {:fred nil} "anything"))
; => false
```

Comment: Yes, as I want to encapsulate this check, I find this approach rather elegant, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `contains?`:

```clj
user=> (contains? {} :potato)
false
user=> (contains? {:potato nil} :potato)
true
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this would give `(contains? {:potato true} :potato)` to be `true`, and I am interested only in checking `nil`. I can use a combination of `contains?` and `nil?`, but this is a little cumbersome, so I decided to ask the question.

Comment: Ah, my bad - I misread the title.